# VB - Count of Each Number in a File

Tags: vb.net

​I'm trying to write code that will
read a text file of numbers similar to this

```
 1234
 5678
 0123
```

and count the total times each number
 is repeated in the file

I can open the file and parse the contents
 to a list box but I don't know how to count
 the total number of times each 0-9 appears in
 the entire file.

I was hoping that someone could tell me
 in theory, how to attack this.

I'm a relative beginner with VB using Visual Studio 2012.
I'm not a student.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Well, maybe you could show us the code you have tried so far to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's `GroupBy` to create a `Dictionary(Of String, Int32)`:

```
Dim numberCounts As Dictionary(Of String, Int32) = File.ReadLines("Path").
     GroupBy(Function(line) line.Trim()).
     ToDictionary(Function(group) group.Key, Function(group) group.Count())
```

So each dictionary key is a (unique) number in the file and the value is it's count.

If you instead want to know the number each digit(0-9) is contained in the file:

```
Dim digitCounts As Dictionary(Of Char, Int32) = File.ReadLines("Path").
     SelectMany(Function(line) line.Where(AddressOf Char.IsDigit)).
     GroupBy(Function(digitChar) digitChar).
     ToDictionary(Function(group) group.Key, Function(group) group.Count())
```

Answer (score 0):

First, parsing the data to a listbox is not advisable. You should not use user interface elements to store data. User interface elements are for displaying data and accepting input from the user. Never use them for anything else. By separating concerns, you make your application easier to debug, easier to understand and easier to modify (imagine you want to completely change the interface so it doesn't use listboxes... kinda hard to do if that's how you're doing data storage).

Second, the tool you are looking for is the Dictionary class in the system.collections.generic namespace. Try reading the description of the class and see if you can figure out how you can use it to solve the problem. Post some code if you can't get that to work.